# How can I rotate Youtube videos as if on a mirror? (!!Not 90degree rotations by ctrl+shift+arrow!!)

Tags: display

add the google chrome extention named "video mirroring".

i was searching an answer for flipping the computer screen "on Y axis" and came across to the question on Superuser;

```
"How can I horizontally flip/invert my monitor (not rotate)?"
https://superuser.com/q/554589/1768390
```

the OP wanted an answer to the same question as i did but few people understood and gave him some reliable ideas while some answered by mentioning some useless software without even comprehending the need of the OP.(and they had upvotes lol)

my own need was to flip videos on Youtube, ON THE Y AXIS. being a flipper in bed myself, i flip very often before sleep and i like to watch videos on subjects i like. so i put a real mirror on the opposite side of the bed to watch videos as i flip to the otherside, lol.

the problem is, the videos i watch often include graphics or presentation pages that include scripts on them. so the scripts were reversed like the "ambulance" prints on the ambulance vehicles, duh.

the OP of the "How can I horizontally flip/invert my monitor (not rotate)?" question needed a solution to flip the whole screen so the solution i found to my problem wont satisfy that need. yet i created account on Superuser, thinking if a person finds that question and comes across to my answer that will solve their situation but Superuser doesnt let me to answer the question because of being a new user.

so i decided to create a similar question and answer it myself. i dont know if this is against rules but i wasted 15 mins of my life to be helpful to people would need similar solution like watching things on youtube with subtitles etc while watching it through a reflected mirror for their personal reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think that question it may not be fully the same as yours bcs you only need to flip a HTML video that can be achievable by simply applying this **CSS** lines in the **Browser** ( after choosing the video tag `<video>` )

```
transform: rotateY(180deg);
-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-transform:rotateY(180deg); /* Firefox */
```

in his case he needs it **outside a browser** so the **software** solutions for his question it will work for you too but **not vise versa**